# Manipulate content in pdf using pypdf

Tags: python, pypdf

I have a method that uses PyPDF4 1.27.0 to change the color of all black objects in a pdf-file. Now I want to switch to pypdf 3.6.0, but I cannot figure out how to port this code.

I’ve reduced the code to a small working example. This examples changes the color of all black objects into red.

```
from PyPDF4 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from PyPDF4.pdf import ContentStream
from PyPDF4.generic import TextStringObject, NameObject, NumberObject, FloatObject
from PyPDF4.utils import b_

with open("test.pdf", "rb") as f:
    source = PdfFileReader(f, "rb")
    output = PdfFileWriter()

    for page in range(source.getNumPages()):
        page = source.getPage(page)
        content_object = page["/Contents"].getObject()
        content = ContentStream(content_object, source)

        i = 0
        for operands, operator in content.operations:
            if operator == b_("rg") or operator == b_("RG"):
                if operands == [0, 0, 0]:
                    rgb = content.operations[i][0]
                    content.operations[i] = ([FloatObject(1.0),
                                              FloatObject(0.0),
                                              FloatObject(0.0)],
                                             content.operations[i][1])
            i = i + 1

        page.__setitem__(NameObject('/Contents'), content)
        output.addPage(page)

    with open("test_colored.pdf", "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)
```

It feels like I’ve tried everything, but I’m really getting nowhere. This is where I am right now:

```
import pypdf
from io import BytesIO

with open("test.pdf", "rb") as fh:
    bytes_stream = BytesIO(fh.read())

# Read from bytes_stream
pdfReader = pypdf.PdfReader(bytes_stream)

page = pdfReader.pages[0]
content_object = page.get_contents()
content = content_object.get_data()

content = content.replace(b'0 0 0 rg', b'0.99 0.0 0.0 rg')
content = content.replace(b'0 0 0 RG', b'0.99 0.0 0.0 RG')

writer = pypdf.PdfWriter()

# Somehow add the content to new_page ??

writer.add_page(new_page)

with open("test_colored.pdf", "wb") as f:
    writer.write(f)
```

I've tried to find and equivalent to `content = ContentStream(content_object, source)` that lets me iterate over the content in the same way as before `for operands, operator in content.operations:`, but I haven't found one.

The next problem is that I don't know how to create a page from the content, which I can then add to the writer.

Please give me some pointers on how this is done in pypdf 3.6.0. I've already got it working on PyPDF2 1.26.0, PyPDF4 1.27.0 and PyMuPDF (fitz) 1.21.1, but I would really like to switch to pypdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I feel stupid. Turns out most of the problems I was having was due to pypdf being installed using pip and simultaneously having a pypdf folder in the folder where I had my Python script.

Now I've managed to find the correct methods in pypdf 3.7.0 (latest version). This examples changes the color of all black objects into red.

```
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter, generic, _utils

with open("test.pdf", "rb") as f:
    source = PdfReader(f, "rb")
    output = PdfWriter()

    for page in range(len(source.pages)):
        page = source.pages[page]
        content_object = page["/Contents"].get_object()
        content = generic.ContentStream(content_object, source)

        i = 0
        for operands, operator in content.operations:
            if operator == _utils.b_("rg") or operator == _utils.b_("RG"):
                if operands == [0, 0, 0]:
                    rgb = content.operations[i][0]
                    content.operations[i] = (
                        [generic.FloatObject(1.0), generic.FloatObject(0.0), generic.FloatObject(0.0)], content.operations[i][1])
            i = i + 1

        page.__setitem__(generic.NameObject('/Contents'), content)
        output.add_page(page)

    with open("test_colored.pdf", "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should accept your answer :-) (and you should only use `pypdf` - I don't see any reason to use PyPDF2 / PyPDF3 / PyPDF4 anymore. I'm the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2)